# PHP Method in Class not returning data from database

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Ok this should be fairly simple.

I have a table which contains content of 3 different textboxes the method inside my class should get the content to insert into textboxes.

Example TextBoxes (TextArea) where content should be entered.

[image]

My Method

```
public function LoadBoxes(){
        $db = DB::getInstance();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM beta_letsgocontent";
        $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute();
        $boxes = $stmnt->fetchAll();
            foreach ($boxes as $box) {
                $data[] = array('Low' => $box['boxLow'],
                    'Medium' => $box['BoxMedium'],
                    'High' => $box['BoxHigh']);
            }
            return $data;
        }//function
```

Here is my table (image below) so data / content from table should get inserted into the textboxes.

[image]

So when I do a test on content.php where I call the class method as such:

```
require_once('../classes/class.content.php');
$boxes = new Contents();
$boxes->LoadBoxes();
var_dump($boxes);
```

I get the following back:

[image]

**Problem**

**As can be seen the array keys get returned however the data from database is not matched to array keys or returned by the method**...I am stumped and have no idea what I am doing wrong here?

Any suggestions where I am going wrong? Could it be that I am not connecting to database correctly?

However if it was a database connection error I believe I would have received an error

Please keep in mind im a student and still learning.

**UPDATE**

Connection Schema

```
class Db {
    private static $instance = NULL;

    private function __construct() {}

    private function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
            self::$instance = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=beta', 'root', '', $pdo_options);

        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

I just did the following on a test.php page which returned correct results.

```
require('connection.php');

function LoadBoxes(){
    $db = DB::getInstance();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM beta_letsgocontent";
    $stmnt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmnt->execute();
    $boxes = $stmnt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($boxes as $box) {
        $box[] = array('Low' => $box['BoxLow'],
        'Medium' => $box['BoxMedium'],
        'High' => $box['BoxHigh']);
    }
return $box;
}//function

print_r(LoadBoxes());
?>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add your database schema. Also since you are not binding anything, you can use pdo query() function instead of prepare execute

Comment: @Akintunde just added it also see picture of database table I inserted. I have used same connection schema multiple times in past without problems though...

Comment: Do a var_dump($boxes); in the loadBoxes function... let's see what that returns

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee You may want to change the variable name that stores your data inside foreach loop, as you are using same variable $box for iteration as well as storing the data

Comment: @Akintunde please see update 2 I made a test.php page and ran the same code in a function which returned correct results. Dont know it it is of any help except that it shows my connection is working...

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti ok let me try, also please see update 2

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti changed variable name to `$data[]` in foreach loop still same problem

Comment: @Akintunde strangely when I do a `var_dump()` inside method as suggested I get the correct result displayed when page loads....?

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee I don't see `$data[]` anywhere in your question code. Your issue is most certainly related to attempting to array-push to the same variable that is your iteration entry.

Comment: @Phil that was an edit I made on my source code after it was suggested, never updated it on SO question. Didn't make a difference.

Comment: Show the current state of your code in the question. If this **is** the current state, there is a definite problem with what you're doing with the `$box` variable

Comment: @Phil see update still same problem though...

Answer (score 0):

2 issues primary issues;

1. You're returning $data from the class but not populating a variable with the returned array.
2. You are var dumping the object itself.

This should work;

```
require_once('../classes/class.content.php');
$boxes = new Contents();
$data  = $boxes->LoadBoxes();
var_dump($data);
```